# Backbone.localstorage not saving anything, with no errors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, local-storage, marionette

I'm trying to implement backbone.localstorage (https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) in my application, but for some reason it's including it but not actually saving anything to localStorage, but it's also not throwing any errors either.

Here is my model code (I am using RequireJS):

```
      define([
 'backbone',
'common',
'localstorage'
],
function(Backbone, Common) {

//Define the App Namespace before anything else
var APP = Common.app_namespace || {};

APP.Models.ExampleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("ExampleModel"),

  //Set up default values 
  defaults: {
    "user_name" : "awesome name",
    "field 2" : "awesome field"
   }

});

 }
);
```

And here is where I'm calling it (using Marionette's regions):

```
  var exModel = new APP.Models.ExampleModel({
          "user_name" : "name!",
          "field2" : "field!"
        });

main_app_layout.header.show(new APP.Views.ExampleView({model: exModel}));
```

In terms of require, the page is loading, but I just don't think it's doing anything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call the `exModel.save()` method for it to save to localStorage.